# Finding Standard Deviation for Number of Flips to Get Two Consecutive Heads

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

Let $X$ be the discrete random variable defined to be the number of flips of a fair coin until we get two heads in a row.

I already know and understand that $E(X) = 6$. Simply solve $x = 0.5(1+x) + 0.25(2+x) + 0.25(2)$

I would like to find the standard deviation, $\sigma$, for this distribution.

Using $\sigma^2 = E(X^2) - \bigl( E(X) \bigr) ^2$

I tried to find $E(X^2)$ similarly to how I found $E(X)$. But I'm not sure if what I'm doing is "valid" or "appropriate".

$$E(X^2) = 0.5\bigl( 1 + E(X) \bigr)^2 +0.25\bigl( 2 + E(X) \bigr) ^2 + 0.25(2)^2 $$

If we plug in $E(X)$ we get that $E(X^2)=41.5$

However after going through the rest of the calculations, I end up with $\sigma = 2.345$ which definitely doesn't seem correct just from doing a few test runs of this experiment.

How can I correctly find $E(X^2)$? Or how can I better find $\sigma$?

Any help given is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303960/pmf-of-the-number-of-trials-required-for-two-successive-heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The squares should be inside the expectations, not outside:
$$
\begin{align}
E(X^2)
&=E(X^2|T)P(T)+E(X^2|HT)P(HT)+E(X^2|HH)P(HH)\\
&=E((X+1)^2)\cdot \tfrac12+E((X+2)^2)\cdot\tfrac14+2^2\cdot\tfrac14\\
&=\tfrac34E(X^2)+2E(X) + \tfrac{5}{2}
\end{align}
$$
I get $E(X^2)=58$, so $\sigma =\sqrt{58-36}\approx 4.69.$

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you! So in reality when I found $E(X)$ above what is really happening is I am taking $E(X+1)$ for example and by the linearity of expectation I can instead write $E(X) + E(1) = E(X) + 1$ ?

Comment: That's right :)